# Add all the fields to view automatically in csv export

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I am using entity registration module for node registration.Now i wants to export the registrants.

I am using view export module to export registrants list. Its working fine

But as the registration fields is different per node i can not add a fix number of field to export.

I am trying to use global php field, its working for single column.

Is there any alternatives?

What other i have tried?

```
function paticipant_export_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
          if ($view->name == 'paticipants_export') {
            views_db_object::add_item($view->current_display, 'field', 
    'field_data_field_first_name_1', 'field_first_name_1', 
$options = array(
            $handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_first_name_1']['id'] = 'field_first_name_1',
            $handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_first_name_1']['table'] = 'field_data_field_first_name_1',
            $handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_first_name_1']['field'] = 'field_first_name_1',

            ), $id = NULL);


          }
        }
```

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: programmatically build your view.

Comment: Can i achieve this altering the view or can i add fields dynamically to a view?

Comment: I doubt it as it would have to be in hook views pre build. Which is like really only 2 lines of php to make a new named view.

Comment: @tenken till now i have tried to use hook_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) but not able to achieve my requirements.

Comment: Right you can't use `hook_views_pre_view` because the query has already run and the data retrieved by Views. This is why you could use `hooks_views_pre_build` to add fields before the query is built, a similar question (changing a view before it is run) can be seen here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-set-views-pager-settings alternatively try this http://dropbucket.org/node/1178

Comment: The alternative link i have already tried using hook_views_pre_view, now i am trying solve using hooks_views_pre_build. if present could you please give some example for adding fields dynamically using hooks_views_pre_build?

Comment: Since you are exporting, its not a daily process, So programmatically build your view, find all the registration fields and try with view query alter, you will get data, after this obviously some field data will be empty for some users.

Comment: @heykarthikwithu can we add fields dynamically by using view alter query hook?

Comment: Since registration fields is different per node you can not able add a fix number of field to export, but inside the hook we'll have over own query which gets all fields, for each node.

Comment: @heykarthikwithu yes you are right, i am already tried "hook_views_pre_view" and "hooks_views_pre_build" also getting all the fields inside hook but unable to add new fields to a view programmatically. I have added my code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a really stupid suggestion but why dont you just edit the view and add all the registration fields manually. The view will have empty cells for fields thats not a part of the registration type at a specific row, but thats something you'll get anyways.

Another way to go is to skip views alltogether and export data with a module of your own using the entity api. You aparently are writing a module to override view fields above so you have already started down that road (so to speak)